# Polynomial division LFSR

Tags: digital-logic

Here is the schematic for LFSR (Linear Feedback Shift Register) polynomial division by \$w(x) = n_3x^3 + n_2x^2 + n_1x + n_0\$

[image]

\$\oplus\$ denotes adder without carry logic, (nx) denotes multiplicator by \$n_x\$ coefficient and boxes are flip-flops.

The drawback of this solution is that polynomial \$w(x)\$ has to be of constant degree, otherwise the circuit won't work.

Are there are any solutions to build LFSR division unit which is able to divide by polynomial of non-constant-degree (there is specified maximally allowed degree)? Or maybe some not-LFSR units?

Comment: What's the link to the image? we'll add it

Comment: Here you are http://img269.imageshack.us/i/dzielenie.png/

Comment: If no is zero, wouldn't that give a polynomial of degree two?  If your circuit were expanded to 33 bits, that would allow for all polynomials up to degree 33 (albeit with some delay before data started flowing into the polynomial).  Another approach is to have input data feed through a single XOR before feeding through a straight shift register, and have the taps of the shift register get multiplied by a polynomial and fed into the input xor.  That approach requires the polynomial to be written differently, but it can solve the same problems as the one you've drawn.

Comment: n0 is lowest coefficient. If w(x) would be changed to polynomial of degree 2, then n3 should be zero, but then division will not work, because on the top line will be always signal zero.

Comment: If n0 is zero, and all the other n's are shifted over one place so that n3 becomes the old n2, n2 becomes the old n1, and n1 becomes the old n0, the circuit would seem to be an order-two polynomial the input delayed by one input stage.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There should be some control unit to place coefficients of w(x) in proper multiplicators according to w(x)'s degree. There is however one bad case and it is when w(x) will be of degree 0 - constant, then this should not work. Thanks.

Comment: There are many polynomials that are crummy, and there are some that work well (maximal length cycles) that are commonly used. I'm curious, why the need for flexibility in hardware? Usually it's sufficient to pick one polynomial and stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to have a multiplexer between the IN bit and the LFSR which will route the input bit around unneeded LFSR stages. This would require lines to not only deactivate unused stages but to reroute the output bit from one stage to another. It's possible but is going to be fairly hardware expensive. What is the purpose of having a variable-degree LFSR in hardware?

Comment: Euclid's algorithm for polynomials. I think that supercat's answer is all right, which is to shift polynomial coefficients to max right part of LFSR and assigning zero to unused multiplicators.

Comment: I won't -1 this, but a multiplexer seems overly complicated to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

In binary, your various nx coefficients are 0 and 1, so you either gate the feedback into the (+) units (XOR, btw), or you don't. The easiest way to do that is to put an AND gate where each coefficient is, with the inputs being the fed-back bit and the appropriate bit of the polynomial N. That way each stage either gets the feedback or 0 fed into the corresponding XOR (+). Noting that anything XOR'd with 0 is itself, the effect of the zero is the same as just not having the XOR at that point.